# tvOS AVPlayerItem external artwork metadata size

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayeritem

Ok so I’m adding an image to the Info tab of the AVPlayerViewController as such:

```
let artworkMetadataItem = AVMutableMetadataItem()
artworkMetadataItem.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
artworkMetadataItem.identifier = AVMetadataCommonIdentifierArtwork
artworkMetadataItem.value = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) 
playerItem.externalMetadata.append(artworkMetadataItem)
```

I just want to know how to make that image larger, it shows up as a tiny picture (65x97), but it is 320x480 in actuality so it should look much larger. How do I increase the size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image scales according to the size of title and description metadata items.
You can add AVMutableMetadataItem with AVMetadataCommonKeyDescription identifier and @"\n\n\n" value.

I wish there was a better way to do it, but I couldn't find any..

Comment: I had found this out as well recently, while I wish there was a better way as well, it seems to be the only way to currently accomplish this.